# solr, solrj: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset

Tags: solr, solrj, socketexception

I have a multi-threaded application in solrj 4. The threads (max 25) share one connection to HttpSolrServer. Each thread is running one query. This worked fine for a while, until it finally crashed with the following messages:

```
Jan 12, 2013 12:52:15 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
Jan 12, 2013 12:52:15 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
```

I would like to catch this exception and reset the connection to the server. I don't get the whole stack trace with the above message, so I'm not sure where to do this. The only place I reference the server is for making a query with:

```
server.query( query )
```

But the only exception this throws is SolrServerException, which I'm currently handling.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

FYI, this is how I'm setting up the initial server connection:

```
    server = new HttpSolrServer(url);
            server.setSoTimeout(0);
            server.setDefaultMaxConnectionsPerHost(50);
            server.setMaxTotalConnections(128);
```

Comment: What makes you think that HttpSolrServer is thread-safe?

Comment: I read that in the documentation: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj. And tested it out.

Comment: what is your server operation system?